# Manipulating string in cmd prompt

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd

Suppose I have a environment variable like version with value`Version-1-0-12-1`. How can I convert it to a string format like `1.0.12.1` from the command prompt ? The shell equivalent would be to use `IFS`. How to do it in Windows command prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
set "var=Version-1-0-12-1"
set "var=%var:*-=%"
set "var=%var:-=.%"
echo %var%
```

Comment: It also displays the word `Version` along with it. I get the result as `Version.1.0.12.1`. But I need it as `1.0.12.1`

Comment: Thanks I have included this line so that it displays the desired result `set "var=%var:D.=%"`